# Why does the javascript if/else statement not working

Tags: javascript, user-agent

I tried to write a small code, but it's not working.

How should it work:
there is a if function statement, which filters between iPhone/iPod and else

The problem is, that it's not working.

```
$(function() {
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
        function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "360px";
    }
        function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
} else {
    function openNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "360px";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "360px";
    }
    function closeNav() {
      document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
      document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
  }
    
});
```

Tank you guys!

Comment: Declare all your functions one place. And then in one of those functions, have the logic with the if-else and then just call the function, instead of declared new functions inside the brackets.

Comment: Don't define functions conditionally; instead, move the condition into the functions.

Comment: *What* is not working? You code does nothing at the moment.

Comment: Also, this could all be done via CSS, by adding and removing classes and using media queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your code as below depending on your requirements.

```
 function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "360px"; //common code

    if(!((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)))) {
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "360px";
    }
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0"; //common code
    if(!((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)))) {
        document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }   
  }
  

$(function() {
   // Call your function from here as per the requirement.
    openNav();
    closeNav();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to declare the functions elsewhere then just call them within the if/else statement.

**1- Declare all functions:**

```
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "360px";
}
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
function openNavWithMargin() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "360px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "360px";
}
function closeNavWithMargin() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

**2- Call them in the if/else statement:**

```
$(function() {
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    openNav();
    closeNav();
} else {
    openNavWithMargin();
    closeNavWithMargin();
  }
    
});
```